# Meteor subscriptions using deps

Tags: regex, meteor

I'm trying to implement a searching feature in a Meteor application that re-subscribes/publishes a collection on every search, so there is only the exact Collection necessary in the client. I'm creating a reactive variable `searchString`, then changing it to the text in the search box on every search, then splitting the string into tags:

```
// Client
var searchString = "";
var searchStringDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getSearchString = function(){
    searchStringDep.depend();
    return searchString;
}

var handle = Deps.autorun(function(){
    var tags = getSearchString().split(" ");

    tags = _.map(tags, function(tag){
            return tag.replace(/[^\w]/g, "");
    }).filter(function(t){
        return t.toLowerCase();
    });
    Meteor.subscribe('results', tags);
});

Template.library.events({
    'submit form': function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        searchString = ev.target.search.value;
        searchStringDep.changed();
    }
})
```

Then, publishing a new Collection on the server, based on the tags:

```
// Server
Meteor.publish('results', function(tags){
    regTags = _.map(tags, function(tag) { return new RegExp(tag)});
return Samples.find({tags: {$in: regTags}})
});
```

So I'm trying to match on regexes, but am having a weird issue where the subscription only changes when I **add** another tag, but changing existing tags fails.

So if the first searchString was `tag1` and the second `tag1 tag2`, it works fine.

But if the first is `tag1` and the second is `tag2`, the Collection doesn't update.

Any help is appreciated...I'm a beginner to Meteor, so if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, all suggestions are welcome. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

```
'change #search': function(){
   Meteor.subscribe('sampleResults', $('#search').val()); // or if you want on submit it's the same idea
}
```

and publish like

```
Meteor.publish('sampleResults, function(text){
   return Samples.find({tags: {$regex: text}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) Meteor has a very nice way of setting up reactive variables with the [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) component. I would suggest using that rather than creating another dependency for a variable.

2) The name that you are subscribing to: `results` is different than what is published on the server `sampleResults` and that can cause issues.

3) If you are on Meteor >= 0.9.1 you should be using `Tracker` and not `Deps`. You can use `Deps` if you want, but the new updated API is `Tracker` and is probably more stable. See the [changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v091-2014-sep-04) for more details on that.

4) You don't have to set your Deps.autorun function equal to a variable. So you can have it as:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  // Code here
});
```

Comment: Re: 2) that was actually a typo in this post, but thank you :)
Re: 1) That definitely is a better choice, did that instead of Deps/Tracker and it's quite nice.

I am still, though, having the issue that unless the `tags` array includes all previous tags, the client-side Collection won't update. The tags are correct in the `publish` & `subscribe` methods, but for some reason it won't work unless the new `tags` is a superset of the previous `tags` object.